# how to check wasted renders in component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to debug performance issues in a React app,there is any method or 'devtools' or any means to check the performance of my component to prevent the failure of wasted renders

Comment: The package [Why did you update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) shows you all rerenders and why these happen. Very usefull in trying to look for unnecessary rerenders

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render , its a more maintained up to date version of why-did-you-update (https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) , it will print warnings in your console whenever an unnecessary re-render happens in one of your components.

Common optimisations you can do to prevent unnecessary renders include using PureComponent instead of Component, or use React.memo for function components, as well as hoist styles/object literals and function declarations outside of your render functions as they return a new reference every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html

Specifically take a look on `printwasted` https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html#printwasted

> “Wasted” time is spent on components that didn’t actually render
>   anything, e.g. the render stayed the same, so the DOM wasn’t touched